# Fun Math with php product picker- permutations, combinations, something in between

Tags: php, magento, math, permutation

I have a product configurator for a web store. I must generate a "simple product sku" for every possible combination of items. The item is a box containing bags of potato chips. The box can be divided into 1, 2 or 3 compartments for different flavors.

1 compartment is trivial. Just iterate through the flavors and spit out a sku for each.
2 compartments is still easy: just use a combination (N choose 2) using the php Math_Combinatorials library.

3 compartments is hard!

Unlike the 2 compartment option where flavors must be unique, with three compartments you can have say:

BBQ, BBQ, PLAIN

However, we don't want to make a sku for

BBQ, BBQ, PLAIN and PLAIN, BBQ, BBQ

So, this is neither a combination or permutation function anymore.

My idea is to generate the permutations, then assign a numeric value to each flavor, add each line up, and if two lines add to the same number, they are a duplicate combination.
Only duplicate combinations should add up to the same values. I'm thinking of this in terms of how Unix File system permissions work- the octal numbers for read, write and execute add up to 7 in octal. Does anyone know how to choose the correct values (1,2,4 in unix perms) to make this work?

Any other approaches come to mind?

Thanks!

Comment: There are extensions to Magento which support product bundling, have you considered looking at one of these?

Comment: I can see how you might get the idea that unix permissions are added up to get 7 (as 1+2+4=7) but the value is actually calculated using `bitwise operators`.  Permissions are "added" up using `bitwise or` so (1 | 2 | 4) = 7.  Permissions are "subtracted" using `bitwise not` and `bitwise and` so to remove exec bit you do 7 & ~(2) == 7 & 5 = 5. The reason this works is because each permission is unique. That is it can't be used more than once like the flavors can be, for example `wxx` is not a valid unix permission.  So this approach wouldn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I totally understand the question but what about this:

```
<?php

//Generate fake combo
$choices = array('bbq', 'plain', 'one', 'two', 'three');
$combo = array();

$total = rand(1,6);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $total; $x++) {
    $combo[] = $choices[array_rand($choices)];
}

var_dump($combo);

//Make SKU
$combo = array_unique($combo);
sort($combo);

$sku = implode('-', $combo);
echo $sku;
```